# Apps Script: CSV attachment to Google Sheet error - Could not parse text

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a simple function to extract a CSV attachment from my Gmail to a Google Sheet. It works perfectly for all my other CSVs except for one.

This is the script I am running:

```
function getCsvFromGmail() {
  // Get the newest Gmail thread based on sender and subject
  var gmailThread = GmailApp.search("from:test@gmail.com subject:\"testfile\"", 0, 1)[0];
  
  // Get the attachments of the latest mail in the thread.
  var attachments = gmailThread.getMessages()[gmailThread.getMessageCount() - 1].getAttachments();
  
  // Get and and parse the CSV from the first attachment
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachments[0].getDataAsString());
  

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

The error I am receiving:

> Exception: Could not parse text.

Here is a link to the sample dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MNI01XK2HmZ8Nedm9-3U9mjEsls0hoqe/view?usp=sharing

The error could be due to the line break on `field19`. Is there a way I can add in an extra line of code to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  It turns out its not `\n` but `\r`

```
var attachment = attachments[0].getDataAsString();
attachment = attachment.replace(/\r/g," ");
  
// Get and parse the CSV from the first attachment
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment);
```